# open office database password protection

Tags: openoffice.org

I have a question regarding password protection to a table I created when I developed my database using Open Office.
I want to know how can I make a single table as password protected?
eg,
I have a database named Data
I created a table named Data-table
How can I provide a password protection on this table in open office?

Comment: Have you considered creating a standalone form for your users (e.g. a Word or Calc file with form controls as needed by your users), and making the Base file itself unaccessible to your users?

Answer (score 2):

In any database, access permissions are granted to specific database users.  So in the initial OpenOffice Base connection setup you need to choose a specific user.  (If you do not choose a specific user, the default is the `SA` account which has rights to all tables.)

To grant access, you need to execute a `GRANT` statement for that user.  Examples using mysql are given at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON db1.table1 TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

If you are using the default HSQLDB engine with both the client and database in a single file, then in order to connect as a specific user, I think you need to convert it to a more powerful client/server setup.

To do this, you can either unzip the .odb file and extract the HSQLDB files (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14664820/5100564)), or copy the data into a mysql database or other database of your choice.  Once the data is in a separate database, it should not be hard to do what you are asking.